# Does weapon type determine material drops from wild animals?

Tags: elden-ring

Anecdotally, I feel as though once I switched from curved swords and daggers to a curved greatsword, wild animals stopped dropping items as much. Is this the case, or just in my head? Does weapon type have any determining factors in how frequently wild animals drop materials?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know. The possibility of droprate increase by the entities you kill depends only on the level of arcane you have or if you use various items to increase this probability.

Some entities obviously have a lower droprate than others depending on their probability of being found around in the Lands Between.

Comment: What is the interregnum?

Comment: The Interregnum is a vast territory ruled by Queen Marika the Eternal and the main setting of Elden Ring

Comment: @EnricoPinatto in English, the game localizes that as “The Lands Between”; I’ve edited your answer.